# Not detecting network card in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vmware

In VMware workstation I have installed CentOS 7 but it is not showing any network card.

When type `lspci` I am geting:

```
:*-2:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB1.1 UHCI Controller
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 10)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371 / Creative Labs CT2518 [AudioPCI-97] (rev 02)
02:03.0 USB controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller
02:05.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 10)
```

This is my NIC status:

[image]

Why am I not detecting network card in CentOS 7?

Comment: Did you try install VMware tools ?

Comment: network card are active on VM controls ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I installed CentOS in VMware I had selected a wrong version from the drop down list in VMware workstation's OS selecting part.

After I installed with correct version now it's working fine.